# Querying join tables with Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Im using Laravel Eloquent to make a join query.
Here are my Models

**My Queue Schema:**

```
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->string('task');

    $table->string('qustatus');

    $table->boolean('inqueue');

    $table->integer('user_id')->index();

    $table->timestamps();
```

**Queue Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Queue extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

**my User Schema:**

```
$table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('fcmToken')->nullable();
```

**User Model:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function queues()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Queue');
    }
}
```

here i'm trying to get the `fcmToken` for all the users with `inqueue` set to `1`or `true`
I have tried to use '$queue = Queue::with('user')->get();' which returns the entire data. but failed to filter it or find any article with similar sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just in case anyone else is wondering, this is how i did it.

```
$queue = DB::table('queues')
            ->select(
                'queues.id',
                'queues.inqueue',
                'users.fcmToken'
            )
            ->join(
                'users',
                'users.id','=','queues.user_id'
            )
            ->where(['queues.inqueue' => true])
            ->get();
```